# I can't get the canvas inside of a toplevel window to be scrolled by the scrollbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I have followed a tutorial on youtube on how to do a scrollbar in python and it worked for the person but not for me. After copying what he has done and running I got a scrollbar on my screen but it seems to do nothing. Now I've jumped over to another tutorial and the guy there does it differently and now I'm stuck in no-man's-land where I rapidely lose my hope.
Here is the piece of code:

```
    # Content
    # scrollbar
    canvas = tk.Canvas(window_automation_creator, scrollregion=(0,0,2000,5000))
    canvas.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(window_automation_creator, orient='vertical', command=canvas.yview)
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    scrollbar.place(relx=1,rely=0,relheight=1,anchor='ne')
    frame_canvas = tk.Frame(canvas).pack()
    canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame_canvas, anchor='nw')


    # 'add' button
    button_add = tk.Button(frame_canvas, text='ADD', width=10, height=2).pack()

    # test
    for i in range(100):
        i = tk.Button(frame_canvas, text=i).pack()
```

I have kept rewinding and kept not getting why my scrollbar doesn't work, I would appreciate an honest answer. Everything loads in fine and I don't get an error before running the program and after closing it. Hope the piece of code helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `frame_canvas` is `None`, which causes it and its children to appear in the root window. It is `None` because you set it to the result of calling `pack`, and `pack` always returns `None`.

You need to create `frame_canvas` and then call `pack` on separate lines.

```
frame_canvas = tk.Frame(canvas)
frame_canvas.pack()
```